# Is the following $3\times 3$ matrix with rational entries invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $(a,b,c)\neq(0,0,0)$ where $a$,$b$, and $c$ are rational numbers. Is the $3\times 3$ matrix
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
                    a & 2c & 2b \\
                    b & a & 2c \\
                    c & b & a
                  \end{matrix}\right)$$
always invertible? The determinant worked out to be $a³-6abc+2b³+4c³$ which doesn't seem to be very illuminating. I tried considering three cases $a\neq 0$, $b\neq 0$, and $c\neq 0$, but am not getting anywhere! Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more about the context of this problem (i.e. is it for a class, from a book, etc)? I can only guess at what you're intended to do; my suggestion is to examine the linear operator $$T\left( \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix}\right) =  \begin{pmatrix} 2c \\ a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: You can try with row reducd method.

Comment: I have to admit I don't understand these hints.  It will always boil down to whether the determinant is zero.

Comment: I was going for using the fact that $T$ defines an irreducible $\mathbb Q[T]$-module, since its characteristic polynomial is irreducible. Wasn't sure whether that was out of bounds or not though, depending on whether or not this is for an abstract algebra course...

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I guess I don't know enough abstract algebra to see how this argument would work.

Comment: I'm on my phone, so I don't really want to type out the full argument. Somebody else can feel free to flesh it out for Stephen's benefit.

Comment: Folks, this was my simple-minded attempt to prove that if $(a,b,c)\neq (0,0,0)$ then the element $a+b2^{1/3}+c4^{1/3}$ will have an inverse in the cubic field ${\bf Q}(2^{1/3})$. This is clear since $x^3 -2$ is irreducible in ${\bf Q}[x]$ and therefore generates a maximal ideal and this element lies in the quotient field ${\bf Q}[x]/(x^3 - 2)$. But by asking the question of directly seeking a multiplicative inverse to $a+b2^{1/3}+c4^{1/3}$ naively, I was led to this problem. I am so happy that JMoravitz answered it directly and simply below.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think I figured it out.  $T^3 -2I = 0$, and $x^3-2$  is irreducible over the rationals.  So $aI + bT + cT^2$ cannot be zero for any rationals $a,b,c$ except $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith not quite, $I$, $T$, and $T^2$ are linearly independent over any ground field (at least in characteristic $0$). What makes the situation different over $\mathbb Q$ is, for any nonzero vector $v \in \mathbb Q^3$, it is necessarily the case that $v$ cannot generate a proper invariant subspace for $T$ (as that would yield a factorization of $x^3-2$), so $v, Tv, T^2 v, T^3 v, \ldots$ span $\mathbb Q^3$. A little linear algebra and you conclude that $v, Tv, T^2v$ form a basis for $\mathbb Q^3$. Moreover, $v, Tv, T^2 v$ form the columns of the matrix given in the exercise.

Comment: The general principle here is, for $A$ a unital associative algebra and $M$ an irreducible $A$-module, any nonzero element of $M$ generates $M$ as an $A$-module. In this case plug in $A = \mathbb Q[T]$ and $M = \mathbb Q^3$ with $T$ acting as defined in my first comment.

Comment: In any case, the upshot here is I now understand that OP was going for something more like JMoravitz's number theoretic solution, rather than my "indirect" abstract algebraic solution. :) @student You should accept JMoravitz's answer!

Comment: I did! It is a simple and direct arithmetic solution. Your comments are clearly worth pondering seriously though!

Comment: In fact, I think JMoravitz's argument generalizes to cubic fields of the form ${\bf Q}(k^{1/3})$ where $k$ is a cube-free integer. The determinant is a homogenous cubic form, and one argues by reducing ${\rm mod}k$. I haven't checked the details though!

Answer (score 7):

Let $d$ be the common denominator of these rational numbers.  If your original matrix were non-invertible then so too would be $d$ times the matrix and all entries would be integers.  Similarly, we can divide by their greatest common divisor while keeping the matrix non-invertible.

We may as well assume then that $a,b,c$ are all integers with at least one non-zero such that $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$.  So, the question becomes, other than the trivial solution, if there exist *integers* $a,b,c$ with $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ such that $a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc=0$.

If such a solution exists, then $a$ must be even because otherwise with $a$ odd we have an odd number plus or minus multiple even numbers equaling zero, an impossibility.

So... replace $a$ by $2x$ with $x$ an integer.  We have $8x^3 + 2b^3+4c^3-12xbc=0$.  Divide everything by two.  $4x^3+b^3+2c^3-6xbc=0$ which is suspiciously familiar to the original equation.

By the same logic, $b$ is also even.  Replacing $b$ by $2y$ and doing the same thing *also* shows that $c$ is even.

This is all a contradiction however as it implies that $2$ is a common divisor of $a,b,c$ contradicting that $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$